# add extra text to existing href

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, href

I have a dynamic filled link like this: `./images/vlajky/br.gif` which is auto loaded in my website. 
I want to change this to `www.customurl.com/images/vlajky/br.gif`

Can I achieve this with some jQuery?

This is my HTML

```
<td class="standardbunkaobr" width="30">
<a href="./index.php?clanek=analyzy&amp;sekce=fotbal&amp;liga=brazilie&amp;lang=en&amp;tab=1&amp;zap=5">
<img src="./images/vlajky/br.gif" border="0" width="15"></a>1
</td>
```

Comment: You should add the relevant HTML to show how the link appears.

Comment: I added my HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`attr(attributeName, function)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) and [`URL API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to parse the pathname of the current src

```
$('.standardbunkaobr img').attr('src', function() {
  return 'http://www.customurl.com' + new URL(this.src).pathname;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the location api to detected your path if you have a directory you need to combine the location pathname

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var Image = location.origin + "./images/vlajky/br.gif".replace("./","/");
 $("#cotainer").append("<img src='" +Image+"'/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cotainer"></div>
```